# Angular array does not have the expected outcome

Tags: angularjs

Am trying to get element from array. But here is unexpected outcome.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in widget['ui_component_format']">
       {{ item }}
        <div ng-repeat="itemEl in item track by $index">
            {{ itemEl }}
        </div>
 </div>
```

The output like

```
["projectNumber", "projectName", "percentComplete", "projectAmountFormatted"]
[


[

"

p

r

o

j

e

c

t

N

u

m

b

e

r

"

,

"

p

r

o

j

e

c

t

N

a

m

e

"

so on

"
]
```

While I want it like this:

```
projectNumber
projectName
percentComplete
projectAmountFormatted
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you think your array is an array object, but is actually a string (and thus each `item` is a char). Have a function in your controller that runs it through [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in widget['ui_component_format']">
       {{ item }}
        <div ng-repeat="itemEl in getJSONitem(item) track by $index">
            {{ itemEl }}
        </div>
 </div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.getJSONitem = function(item) {
    return JSON.parse(item);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19920/)